# Show alert box when closing browser, but not on page reload or refresh using f5 or browser refresh button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i want to show popup to user when my site close by any user. how to detect this event. i have one solution but it will not work on browser refresh click

```
var exit = true;
$(window).on("keydown",function(e){
    if(e.which === 116){
      exit = false;
    }
});
    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
        if (exit === true) {
            return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
        } else {
            return;
        }
});
```

Comment: try with different name instead `exit`.also do with `on()` instead of `bind`

Comment: @prasad its not working. i want to stop reload or don't reload alert box when i click on browser refresh icon

Answer (score 1):

It can be done very simply with the following JavaScript...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

**EDIT**

I don't know of a way to avoid this script firing when a user presses the refresh button in the browser, but there is a way to stop it when they press f5...

**jQuery**

```
//you need to set the variable exit to true first so it fires when f5 is not pressed
var exit = true;

//on keydown event will check if f5 is pressed
$(window).on("keydown",function(e){//begin window on keydown event

    //f5 key code is 116
    if(e.which === 116){//begin if it f5 is pressed

      //set exit to false so the prompt isn't displayed
      exit = false;

    }


});


//bind the beforeunload event to the window
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {

    //if exit = true then display the prompt
    if (exit === true) {

        //display the prompt
        return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
    } else {

        //do nothing, no prompt will be created
        return;

    }


});
```

Don't forget to include jQuery in your `<head>`

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: its not working when i page refresh it will ask reload

Comment: @HarshalKor I don't think it's possible to stop it from firing on the browser button press but I'm sure there is a workaround for an f5 key press... Stand by for an answer with that solution...

Comment: @HarshalKor I've edited my answer to show you how to do that.